# npm start err from react

Tags: reactjs, npm

---

** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.4.0
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

---

C:\Users\asdf\Desktop\scratch3\create-react-app\docusaurus\website>npm start

> @ start C:\Users\asdf\Desktop\scratch3\create-react-app\docusaurus\website
>   docusaurus start

'docusaurus' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `docusaurus start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-25T05_50_44_042Z-debug.log

C:\Users\asdf\Desktop\scratch3\create-react-app\docusaurus\website>npm install
[

Comment: What does it say inside C:\Users\asdf\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-12-25T05_50_44_042Z-debug.log? Feels like you are not in the right directory or you've misspelled something

Comment: yeah the post change my typesetting，I want to start my react ,but npm start is err,that post is on package.json,start err

Comment: It seems docsaurus is missing. Is it in your package.json and did you run ```npm install```?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue it was resolved with

```
yarn upgrade docusaurus --latest
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while working on an open-source project.
I just did upgrade docusaurus to the latest version
**yarn upgrade docusaurus --latest**
and did **yarn audit fix**

make sure you are in the right directory ex. project_name/src where the package.json file exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rm yarn.lock
$ yarn install
$ yarn start
```

Some errors in the website (e.g., missing page, incorrect syntax, and etc.) may cause this issue. You may force re-build, but the easiest workaround I found is to remove the lock and start over.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Added some context.