# How to solve docusaurus yarn start error?

Tags: github, docusaurus

Trying to run a project cloned from **GitHub** and the `yarn start` gave me the following result

'docusaurus' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The issue is solved by doing

1. yarn upgrade docusaurus --latest
2. yarn --force

After performing first step got another error
When trying to run after first step got another error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined`

To solve that i have to do the second step and it works fine

referred two articles

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59475645/npm-start-err-from-react)

[GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/5106)